# Moving horizontally to another layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to download a list of topics from server (e.g. 40) and then put them on a ListView. By swiping left or right you could download another list of topics and put them on a ListView.

ListViews would be like pages that you can scroll horizontally.

A good example of this is Google Reader. You can swipe left or right when you are in a topic to see another topic.

This isn't in fact a big problem but I would like it to look smooth like in Google Reader. It shows how the last page moves off screen and new page moves to middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you might take a look at [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

Comment: A very good post with very good example included, thank you! I was able to show a ListView in ViewPager but unable to set onListItemClick listener for it.

Comment: I'm also having problems reusing the xml containing the ListView since xml can't be reused in Android.

Comment: Actually managed to get it working. Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376613/android-viewpager-and-listviews helped me with my problems with reusing xml. It also helped me realize that I don't need a OnListItemClick listener but OnItemClickListener will do just as fine.