# ViewPager for sorting through many (>20) pages and dynamically updating text

Tags: android, dynamic, android-viewpager

I'm trying to use a viewpager to sort through a list of pages. for my program, the number of pages varies anywhere from 20-35. This number is determined from the size of the "questions" string array variable, pulled from a sql lite database. the code for this is not shown below but I have confirmed that the code is correctly finding the size of the variable and also the values from the database

my issue is that the first page loads but as soon as I try to scroll to the next page, the program crashes. Each page is meant to be identical except for one textview (currentQuestion), which I am attempting to dynamically change based on the current page that is being viewed (e.g., if on page 8, load the 8th variable from the questions variable to display in the currentQuestion textview).

any help would be greatly appreciated! I'd prefer not to individually define each view...

thanks to the users who found this solution (code below from [Android ViewPager and ListViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376613/android-viewpager-and-listviews))

I'm guessing the issue is with the code that I most modified, which is the MainActivity

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    for (int i=0; i<test.count();i++)
    {
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, question));
        pages.add(listview);
    }
    System.out.println("test");
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.milestoneViewPager);
    PageSwiper adapter = new PageSwiper(mContext,pages);
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);
    int currentPage= vp.getCurrentItem();
    TextView currentQuestion= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.milestoneText);
    currentQuestion.setText(question[currentPage]);
}
```

}

And here's the CustomViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Vector<View> pages;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
this.mContext=context;
this.pages=pages;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
View page = pages.get(position);
container.addView(page);
return page;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return pages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
container.removeView((View) object);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the error that you are encountering? nullPointer i think?
what is the PageSwiper class? custom class I assume but why name it as an adapter?

also you are setting the text of the questions only once, in your onCreate method only, it should be part of the loop or something.

to dynamically change your text, try using the viewpager function setOnPageListener

here is an example:

```
vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            TextView txtQuestion= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.milestoneText);
            String currentQuestion = question[position]; // Question from your string array
            txtQuestion.setText(currentQuestion );


        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


        }
    });
```

hope that helps, message me if it helps or if you need anything else