# ListView inside of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

So I have a ListView inside of a ViewPager.

I have the `ListView` in one layout `(add_site.xml)` and an `EditText` field that would populate the `ListView` `onClick` on another layout `(main.xml)`

I'm getting an NPE error because I tried to put the ArrayAdapter globlaly thinking that was the right approach to be able talk to both of those layouts in the `ViewPager`.

Clearly my android dev skills aren't that great. I'm pretty new at this.

So any help is appreciated!

Here's my code.

This is where the PagerAdapter begins

```
 private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    final ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fieldspager);

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        final ArrayList<String> siteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_row, siteList);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);

        int resId = 0;
        View view = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.field01;
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

                return view;

            case 1: //ListView lives in here.
                resId = R.layout.add_site; 
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                Button addSiteButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addSiteButton);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                addSiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      mPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                    }

                });

                //I originally had the ArrayAdapter code here, but thought it needed to be global so I moved it up.

                return view;

            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.main;
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                Button signInButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

                //This is where the EditText lives
                final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //This is where the button click happens
                        siteList.add(0, editText.getText().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        editText.setText("");
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                    }

                });
                return view;
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I'm not 100% percent sure what you want your arrayadapter to do, but the generally advised pattern for interfragment communication is to build (an) interface(s) between the Activity and the fragment. The interface lists the methods in the activity in the you want the fragments to access. The fragments save a reference to the activity cast as the interface in the onattach method. Meanwhile, if you need to call methods in the fragments from the activity, you just define them as public and call them. This pattern cuts down on coupling. I can give a code example in a few hours if you need it.

Comment: where are you getting the npe?

Comment: @fedepaol
I'm getting the NPE at `lv.setAdapter(aa);`

Comment: @anthropomo
Well my issue is based out of lack of knowledge. I probably have things out of order, but just don't know what that order should be. What I want it to do is type something in the `EditText` which is in the `main` layout and it populate the `ListView` on the adjacent layout `add_site`

Comment: My earlier comment was a misreading of your intentions. Add some logging just before your NPE line so we can see which object is null. Something like `if(lv == null) Log.v("lv", "null"); else Log.v("aa", "null")` Then post the logcat.

Comment: @anthropomo No worries! Here's my Logcat
`01-26 17:23:04.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.learn.eeConnect.FieldsActivity$MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FieldsActivity.java:59)
at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:801)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:930)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)`       
I couldn't fit it all. Does this help? Line 59 is. `lv.setAdapter(aa);`

Comment: Did you log to see if `lv` or `aa` is null at line 59? The log should show up just before the NPE.

Comment: @anthropomo ah yes. I got a lv(16774): null

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the immediate cause of your NPE is this line:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

I'm guessing you meant to do something closer to this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_site, null);
```

I'm not clear on your ultimate goals with the code, so I don't think I can advise there, but I think you will find this example to be very informative going forward:

[Android ViewPager and ListViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376613/android-viewpager-and-listviews)

Hang in there. Android UI is messy. Keep asking questions.